# DevExpress UploadControl javascript error in Google Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, favicon

I am using Devexpress UploadControl for MVC in my project. I am using a pop-up for uploading file where the file upload control is placed. If I click the button to trigger that pop-up more than once the upload control text appears as 'undefined'. This issue happens only in Google Chrome

See the acreenshot
[image: Upload exception]

The code for UploadControl is used as followed:

```
<dl class="uploadProviderDoc">
            @Html.DevExpress().UploadControl(settings =>
               {
                   settings.Name = "Document";
                   settings.ClientSideEvents.TextChanged = "function(s,e){$('label[for=lblUploadMsg]').html(' ');}";
               }).GetHtml()
            @Html.Label("lblUploadMsg", " ")
        </dl>
```

I inspected the console of Google Chrome and found the line of code which throws that error.

```
RedefineInputAttributes: function(textBoxCell, index, isNewElement) {
  textBoxCell.id = this.GetTextBoxCellID(index);
  if(this.IsSlUploadHelperEnabled()) {
   if(this.GetSlUploadHostElement())
    this.slUploadHelper.RedefineSlObjectAttributesInHostElement(index + 1, index, isNewElement);
   else
    this.slUploadHelper.RedefineSlObjectAttributes(textBoxCell, index, isNewElement);
  }
  else {
   var inputElement = _aspxGetChildByTagName(textBoxCell, "INPUT", 0);
   inputElement.id = textBoxCell.id + ASPxClientUploadControlIDSuffix.FileInput;
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null (This exception is thrown here)
   inputElement.name = inputElement.id;
  }
  var fakeInputElement = _aspxGetChildByTagName(textBoxCell, "INPUT", this.IsSlUploadHelperEnabled() ? 0 : 1);
  if(fakeInputElement)
   fakeInputElement.id = textBoxCell.id + ASPxClientUploadControlIDSuffix.FileFakeInput;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery? Looks like there is [an open issue in the DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B196730.aspx).

If that's the case, submit a sample project demonstrating the problem to DevExpress and they will sort it out for you.

Comment: You could make sure it's a compatibility issue by removing jQuery and see if you still get 'undefined' as the control text.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by the **[Chrome V25\V26 repeatedly requests favicon, does not send session cookies](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180764)** problem in the current Chrome build.

Here is the [prove link](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=B232651). Try to implement a solution from that thread.

```
<location path="favicon.ico">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Does it help?

Comment: If this does not help, I suggest that you contact DX support directly.